# SELECT in T-SQL with conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a way too big query using only `SELECT`, and I need to filter it using conditional clause `WHERE`.
Something like this :

```
if (mycondition)

    set @strwhere='conditionalexpression_1'
else

    set @strwhere='conditionalexpression_2'
```

.. then I want to use `@strwhere` in `WHERE`, like this :

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 ............
 from tablex where @strwhere
```

Does any way to do it ? I have tried but... nothing works fine!

Comment: Do you want to use dynamic SQL?

Comment: It is possible to use only dynamic WHERE?

Comment: @parameters will not work like that; but are you using php or C#, you could do the substitutions there - or you have to use dynamic sql (with risks of sql injection to consider)

Comment: sorry what dbms type is it? MySQL or SQL Server

Comment: what condition will your IF have? Will it have if condition on same table tablex?

Comment: And also pls tell that your 2 different where conditions will have same column or different?  In short pls share some sample data and required answer.

Comment: I am using T-SQL , SQL server 2012

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, build the full query first and the execute.

```
SET@SQLQuery='SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tablex where '
If (mycondition)

    set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + 'conditionalexpression_1'
else

    set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + 'conditionalexpression_2'

EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```